# to_datetime not showing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in pandas dataframe like this:

```
>>> print(df['SESSION_DATE'])
0    2008-05-20
1    2013-03-15
2    2014-10-14
3    2006-08-04
4    2006-11-20
Name: SESSION_DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I am trying to create a new column based on this one. But I want the timestamp to show as well. Here is what I tried:

```
>>> df['NEW_COMPL_DTE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SESSION_DATE'])
>>> print(df['NEW_COMPL_DTE'])
0    2008-05-20
1    2013-03-15
2    2014-10-14
3    2006-08-04
4    2006-11-20
Name: NEW_COMPL_DTE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I was hoping the output would include a `00:00:00` after each date. Please advise.

Comment: If the output you want is simply `00:00:00` in all of the rows why don't you simply write it there instead of using datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no timestamp is included, `00:00:00` is assumed, so `pd.to_datetime` does not explicitly display it.

If all you want to do is display it, you may do:

```
pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d %h:%I:%s')
0    2008-05-20 00:00:00
1    2013-03-15 00:00:00
2    2014-10-14 00:00:00
3    2006-08-04 00:00:00
4    2006-11-20 00:00:00
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, this is simpler, but not as neat. You can use this if your column has strings.

```
s + ' 00:00:00'
0    2008-05-20 00:00:00
1    2013-03-15 00:00:00
2    2014-10-14 00:00:00
3    2006-08-04 00:00:00
4    2006-11-20 00:00:00
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use strptime. Like:

```
from datetime import datetime
mywanteddate = datetime.strptime("%s 00:00:00" % (df['SESSION_DATE']), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(mywanteddate) # 2008-05-20 00:00:00
```

Comment: Try running this, before posting it here.

Comment: for python2.7, print is good. But for python3, it should be print("string")

Comment: No, that's not the issue. `df['SESSION_DATE']` is a column of string dates. How do you expect `% df[...]` to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
dates = [datetime(2008, 5, 20), datetime(2013, 3, 15), datetime(2012, 10, 14), datetime(2006, 8, 4), datetime(2006, 11,20)]
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates)
for i in index.astype(np.int64):
    print(pd.to_datetime(i, unit='ns'))
```

to get this

```
2008-05-20 00:00:00
2013-03-15 00:00:00
2012-10-14 00:00:00
2006-08-04 00:00:00
2006-11-20 00:00:00
```