# why Cartesian product of deletes the timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to replicate following date_range to a list by cartesian product:

```
 todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
 time_index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(days=1), end=todays_date, 
 freq='h') # one hour intervals
```

which results in :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-11 00:00:00', '2023-01-11 01:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 02:00:00', '2023-01-11 03:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 04:00:00', '2023-01-11 05:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 06:00:00', '2023-01-11 07:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 08:00:00', '2023-01-11 09:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 10:00:00', '2023-01-11 11:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 12:00:00', '2023-01-11 13:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 14:00:00', '2023-01-11 15:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 16:00:00', '2023-01-11 17:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 18:00:00', '2023-01-11 19:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 20:00:00', '2023-01-11 21:00:00',
           '2023-01-11 22:00:00', '2023-01-11 23:00:00',
           '2023-01-12 00:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

then here is the ids list

```
 ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

then  by doing the following i do the cartesian product

```
pd.DataFrame(product(time_index, ids), columns=['time','id'])
```

but results are not as expected as the Hour:Minute:Seconds part of the Datetime index are dropped and i get something like this :

```
2023-01-11  1
2023-01-11  2
2023-01-11  3
    .
    .
    .
```

How can i properly do this replication while keeping all the DatetimeIndex components, join and merge also returns the same results

I believe it's not a duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625778/to-datetime-not-showing-timestamp) as the timestamp is included in the DatetimeIndex

Comment: What is `print (df.head(20))` ? Answer is it is display problem only if show first 5 or less rows. Because then empty times are not diplayed.

Comment: @jezrael actually print (df.head(20)) returns proper results without removing timestamps, but when i try df in a jupyter cell it removes the timestamps, so what is the problem here? are hour:minute:seconds actually there? because they are critical for later operations

Comment: dont worry, there are correct timestamp. Test it `df = pd.DataFrame(product(time_index, ids), columns=['time','id'])
print (df['time'].tolist())`